# Div content dissapear after jquery.hide() and show()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hello I have problem with my content of div disappearing after a jquery call to hide() and show(), where it's gone.

```
<li class="gg3"><a class="link" href="#" data-rel="content3">Link1</a></li>
<div class="content-container">
    <div id="content3" class="rightWrapperBookmarks">
        <c:forEach var="house" items="${user.houses}">
        <div class="houseBox">
            ${house.mailbox}
            <br> ${house.house}
            <br> ${house.address}
            <br>
            <br>
            <a href="<c:url value="/profile.jsp">
            <c:param name="username" value="${house.username}" />
            </c:url>">Go to user profile</a> <br> <br>
        </div>
        </c:forEach>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is my jquery function, which swaps between my divs to show different content on my page. However swapping between them, makes every content the foreach made disappear.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".link").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.content-container div').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).data('rel')).show();
    });
});
```

How do I make this content persistent to this hide and show?

Comment: edited my post with it.

Comment: yea forgot to put that in. Sorry!

Comment: I just recreated this in a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vfd6bnnc/) and everything works as expected - the DIV is hidden but the content stays in it when checking it out via Development Tools in Chrome

Comment: The content does not reappear for me : /

Comment: have a look your code works fine https://jsfiddle.net/vfd6bnnc/2/

Comment: sry, I misunderstood the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$('.content-container div').hide();
```

to:

```
$('.content-container > div').hide();
```

This just hides the immediate children, not all the descendant DIVs.

The problem you had was that you were showing `.content3`, but the `.houseBox` DIV inside it was still hidden by the original `.hide()`.

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks for for :)

Answer (score 0):

your handleing css code. here this css codes add.
here this codes working in jsfiddle(https://jsfiddle.net/hyoeqwzL/)

```
.hide {display:none!important}
.show {display:block!important}
```

here javascript code

```
$(".link").on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.content-container div').addClass('hide').removeClass('show');
    console.log('#'+$(this).data('rel'))
    $('#' + $(this).data('rel')).addClass('show').removeClass('hide');
    return false;
});
```